# Error al intentar crear un servicio NSD

Tags: java, android-studio, servicio

Estoy intentando crear un servicio para conectarme a la aplicación Kore. Para crear dicho servicio estuve mirando el código de [android developer](https://developer.android.com/training/connect-devices-wirelessly/nsd#java). Literalmente solo he seguido los pasos que me indican en la página. Aún así, al iniciar mi aplicación esta se detiene. 
Este es mi código:

```
package com.nerviosus.koreservice;

import android.app.Activity;

import android.content.Context;

import android.net.nsd.NsdManager;

import android.net.nsd.NsdServiceInfo;

import android.os.Bundle;

import java.net.ServerSocket;

public class MainActivity extends Activity  {

private final String SERVICE_TYPE = "_xbmc-jsonrpc-h._tcp.local.";
private String mServiceName = "NSD-Kore";
private NsdManager mNsdManager;
NsdManager.RegistrationListener mRegistrationListener;



@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    registerService(8080);
    initializeRegistrationListener();

}

public void registerService(int port) {
    NsdServiceInfo serviceInfo = new NsdServiceInfo();

    serviceInfo.setServiceName("KoreService");
    serviceInfo.setServiceType(SERVICE_TYPE);
    serviceInfo.setPort(port);
    mNsdManager = (NsdManager) getSystemService(Context.NSD_SERVICE);
    mNsdManager.registerService(
            serviceInfo, NsdManager.PROTOCOL_DNS_SD, mRegistrationListener);

}
public void initializeRegistrationListener() {
    mRegistrationListener = new NsdManager.RegistrationListener() {

        @Override
        public void onServiceRegistered(NsdServiceInfo NsdServiceInfo) {
            // Save the service name. Android may have changed it in order to
            // resolve a conflict, so update the name you initially requested
            // with the name Android actually used.
            mServiceName = NsdServiceInfo.getServiceName();
        }

        @Override
        public void onRegistrationFailed(NsdServiceInfo serviceInfo, int errorCode) {
            // Registration failed! Put debugging code here to determine why.
        }

        @Override
        public void onServiceUnregistered(NsdServiceInfo arg0) {
            // Service has been unregistered. This only happens when you call
            // NsdManager.unregisterService() and pass in this listener.
        }

        @Override
        public void onUnregistrationFailed(NsdServiceInfo serviceInfo, int errorCode) {
            // Unregistration failed. Put debugging code here to determine why.
        }
    };
}
```

Estos son los errores que aparecen en la consola:

```
2018-12-31 13:23:16.112 1463-1463/? E/adbd: failed to connect to socket 'localabstract:com.nerviosus.koreservice': Connection refused
2018-12-31 13:23:17.179 1748-1764/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
2018-12-31 13:23:18.021 11085-11085/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.nerviosus.koreservice, PID: 11085
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.nerviosus.koreservice/com.nerviosus.koreservice.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: listener cannot be null
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2778)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2856)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1589)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: listener cannot be null
        at android.net.nsd.NsdManager.registerService(NsdManager.java:524)
        at com.nerviosus.koreservice.MainActivity.registerService(MainActivity.java:62)
        at com.nerviosus.koreservice.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:49)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7009)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7000)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2731)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2856) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1589) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807) 
2018-12-31 13:23:18.130 1748-3126/? E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000082da
2018-12-31 13:23:18.131 1748-3126/? E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000082da
2018-12-31 13:23:19.143 1748-1923/? E/TaskPersister: File error accessing recents directory (directory doesn't exist?).
2018-12-31 13:23:31.926 1748-1923/? E/TaskPersister: File error accessing recents directory (directory doesn't exist?).
2018-12-31 13:23:33.127 1748-1764/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
2018-12-31 13:23:44.081 1748-1764/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
2018-12-31 13:23:44.085 1748-1768/? E/BatteryExternalStatsWorker: modem info is invalid: ModemActivityInfo{ mTimestamp=0 mSleepTimeMs=0 mIdleTimeMs=0 mTxTimeMs[]=[0, 0, 0, 0, 0] mRxTimeMs=0 mEnergyUsed=0}
2018-12-31 13:23:49.078 1748-1764/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
2018-12-31 13:23:49.094 1748-1764/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
2018-12-31 13:24:00.005 1748-1764/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
2018-12-31 13:25:05.641 1748-1764/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
2018-12-31 13:24:32.079 1748-1768/? E/BatteryExternalStatsWorker: modem info is invalid: ModemActivityInfo{ mTimestamp=0 mSleepTimeMs=0 mIdleTimeMs=0 mTxTimeMs[]=[0, 0, 0, 0, 0] mRxTimeMs=0 mEnergyUsed=0}
2018-12-31 13:25:36.083 1748-1768/? E/BatteryExternalStatsWorker: modem info is invalid: ModemActivityInfo{ mTimestamp=0 mSleepTimeMs=0 mIdleTimeMs=0 mTxTimeMs[]=[0, 0, 0, 0, 0] mRxTimeMs=0 mEnergyUsed=0}
2018-12-31 13:25:36.084 1748-1764/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
2018-12-31 13:26:43.083 1748-1768/? E/BatteryExternalStatsWorker: modem info is invalid: ModemActivityInfo{ mTimestamp=0 mSleepTimeMs=0 mIdleTimeMs=0 mTxTimeMs[]=[0, 0, 0, 0, 0] mRxTimeMs=0 mEnergyUsed=0}
2018-12-31 13:28:00.004 1748-1764/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
2018-12-31 13:28:00.040 1748-1764/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
2018-12-31 19:17:07.904 11159-11159/com.google.android.calendar E/PrefServiceImpl: Primary account is null
```

Gracias en adelanto, y si puedo mejorar la formulación de la pregunta, agradezco que se mencione.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El mensaje de error de desplegado en el LogCat indica el problema:

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: listener cannot be
>   null

El listener no ha sido inicializado, el método que realiza la inicialización es `initializeRegistrationListener()` y el método donde es utilizado es `registerService()`, si revisas tu código en realidad estas realizando lo contrario:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    ...
    registerService(8080);
    initializeRegistrationListener();

}
```

este debería de ser el orden correcto, inicializar el listener `mRegistrationListener` y posteriormente utilizarlo:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    ...
    initializeRegistrationListener();
    registerService(8080);
}
```

Comment: De acuerdo, voy a probar aunque creo que ya lo intenté de esa forma.

Comment: Intentalo y revisa el LogCat, probablemente tienes otro problema.

Comment: Si tengo otro problema en el LogCat, actualizo esta pregunta o creo una nueva?

Comment: Si quieres agregalo para determinar si es causado por el mismo listener o es otro detalle completamente diferente.

Comment: No hace falta, todo funciona correctamente. Muchas gracias y feliz 2019!

Comment: Excelente Feliz año 2019 @nerviosus